# POST params with spaces in it

Tags: go

How do I make a POST request when the post param has spaces in it? Eg. in bash I would do this:

```
curl -X POST "https://website.com/api" --data-urlencode "key=$SSHKey" <- "ssh-rsa abcde abc@abc.com"
```

I'm using the http.NewRequest method to send POST requests. http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequest

```
reqURL := fmt.Sprintf("https://website.com/api?key=%s", "ssh-rsa abcde abc@abc.com")

client := &http.Client{}
r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", reqURL, nil)
client.Do(r)
```

Comment: the $SSHKey has spaces in the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could URL encode the parameter using [`net.url.Values.Encode`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.Encode):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/url"    

func main() {
    values := url.Values{}
    values.Set("key", "foo bar baz")
    fmt.Println(values.Encode())
}
```

Output:

```
key=foo+bar+baz
```

Comment: Thank you for the question. This is my first upvote for Go :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`url.QueryEscape`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryEscape).

```
reqURL := fmt.Sprintf("https://website.com/api?key=%s",
    url.QueryEscape("ssh-rsa abcde abc@abc.com"))

// https://website.com/api?key=ssh-rsa+abcde+abc%40abc.com
```

Also note that you are talking of POST parameters but you are actually setting GET url parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of languages you encode space with something like `%20` or `+`. I would suggest you to try simple [string](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) replacement. For example:

`strings.Replace(params, " ", "%20", -1)`